# Interface microcontroller as I2C slave

Tags: microcontroller, i2c

How do I configure an I2C enabled microcontroller (NXP P89LPC9321) as a slave for the I2C enabled master? I have done some study on the I2C interface. Please throw some light on this, preferably some sample code or something would also help.

Comment: What devices are you using?

Comment: By reading your microcontroller's datasheet and compiler documentation, if you're using a compiler or by making a software library for that. Exact details depends on type of microcontroller, which you did not provide.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.I use 8051 controller and Keil IDE(as we thought that it is simple enough for the educational purpose).I just wanted to read back the contents that i wrire into the ROM of the slave 8051.

Comment: Just calling it an 8051 is too generic. The original Intel 8051 did not have hardware I2C at all. You need to give us the actual manufacturer and part number.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.Philips is the manufacturer and P89LPC9321 is the part number.

Comment: Philips hasn't made components anymore since 2006. It's NXP now.

Answer (score 5):

The P89LPC9321's [User Manual](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10310.pdf) explains the I2C slave modes on page 76 ff.

Section 11.6.3 explains slave receiver mode, section 11.6.4 addresses slave transmitter mode.

**Further reading**
[P89LPC9321 datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/P89LPC9321.pdf)

Comment: Ya..thanks But i am confused as my slave itself is a microcontroller.Every slave will have an address,that will be provided by the manufacturer.  will a microcrontroller will also have an address? The slave microcontroller itself may be involved in some other activites like an ADC operation,EEPROM write etc.In that case how the request from the master will be handled by this? What are the events in general that happens when a microcontroller slave is requested to read/write a location in it's ROM ? Can anyone throw some light on this?

Comment: @vaidi - Did you read the sections in the user manual I refer to? First paragraph: "To initialize the Slave Receiver Mode, the user should write the slave address to the Slave Address Register (I2ADR)". The microcontroller can switch to master mode to access EEPROM and ADC. It only has to wait until the bus is free. Section 11.6.4: "If bus arbitration is lost in the master mode, the I2C-bus switches to the slave mode immediately and can detect its own slave address in the same serial transfer."